# Is there a way to calculate semantic distance between adjectives relative to a common noun with word2vec embedding?

Tags: word2vec, semantics, cosine-similarity

I would like to develop a human memory experiment, where I need to manipulate the semantic distance of features of a concept. I would like to acquire close and distant semantic features for the same object.
E.g.: “hot coffee” and “strong coffee” would maybe closer semantically than “hot coffee” and “creamed coffee”.

I have a 200 dimensional Hungarian word2vec database with a vocabulary of 200k made from the Hungarian National Corpus. I know that “cosine similarity” is a good index for semantic distance, and I understand how I can calculate this metric between two word-vectors.
My main problem is that I really need the information from the noun too, and I am not sure how to measure the distance accounting for that. Simply measuring the adjectives would not be enough as “hot” and “strong” in terms of “coffee” would definitely have different semantic distance than in the case of “furniture” for instance.

Thank you for any of your help, I would really appreciate any ideas.